# Call a .asmx web Service from another .asmx web service

Tags: c#, web-services

can we call a web service from another web service.

i have tried adding web reference and getting the below erro

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was caught
  Message=The current configuration system does not support user-scoped settings.
  Source=System
  BareMessage=The current configuration system does not support user-scoped settings.
  Line=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)
       at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(SettingsProvider provider)
       at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName)
       at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
       at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
       at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
```

pls help

Comment: both services are in same location? or to sites?

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal both the serives will be hosted in the same machine and same IIS

Comment: inside the same site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the methods to separate class. and access those common methods from that class. so both of the services can share the methods you want.